# Why does new Date(year,month,day) not return an equivialent Date?

Tags: node.js, date

one day I fiddled with vanilla NodeJS using the `node` command line tool. (I am using `node v13.11.0`)

I tried to create a new `Date` at the `01.01.1970`. I used the usual `new Date(year, month, day)` constructor. 
As simple as it sounds, I entered `new Date(1970, 1, 1)` and found out, that it does not return `1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000Z`. Instead, it returns `1970-01-31T12:00:00.000Z`.

Has anyone an Idea, why this constructor does not return the equivalent date?

Comment: 1. `month` is zero based, so `1` means February. 2. The date generated assumes local date and is then transformed to UTC. In your case, this shifts the date by 12 hours back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor does more or less what you think:

```js
x = new Date(1970,1,1)
1970-01-31T14:00:00.000Z
> x.getMonth()
1
> x.getDate()
1
> x.getHours()
0
```

(Note that months count from zero, so you requested the 1st of February).

But if you display the whole date as a string, it's showing the time in UTC, which might not be what you expect.